# getting the last logged in date

Tags: login, zoo-visitor, profile

I have created a user dashboard and am trying to get the last loggin date to show on the homepage.

I tried {last_activity} but got no output. Is there a variable I can use for this? The profile is extended using zoo visitor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Zoo Visitor handles this differently, but you may need to place `{last_activity}` within the `{exp:member:custom_profile_data}` tag.

Have you tried `{exp:member:custom_profile_data} {last_activity} {/exp:member:custom_profile_data}`?

Also, this will display for the current logged-in user unless you show it as part of a larger loop and specify the member_id.

Comment: And since it's a date variable you can use date formatting, e.g. [{last_activity format="%Y-%m-%d"}](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/member/index.html#last-activity).